# How to delete all files in folder XXX

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have many folders in the server with the name XXX.
every folder is in different folder in the tree structure.

i need to delete all files inside that folders, from one root.

```
for /d %i in (*.*) do del %i\*.*
```

this will delete all my files

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /r "\" /d %a in (*XXX*) do @if /i "%~nxa"=="XXX" echo del /s /f /q "%~fa\*.*"
```

Search recursively (`/r`) from the root of the drive for folders (`/d`) matching the `*XXX*` mask. If its name+extension is exactly `XXX`, then delete all the files inside.

The `del` commands are echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to perform the delete operations.

If this is to be used inside a batch file, all `for` command replaceable parameters need to have the percent sign doubled

```
for /r "\" /d %%a in (*XXX*) do @if /i "%%~nxa"=="XXX" echo del /s /f /q "%%~fa\*.*"
```

Comment: It could help to use the `/i` switch after `@if` incase the folder is `Xxx` or `xxx` too.

Comment: @foxidrive, good point. Corrected.